# Spring Boot Integration test random free port

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-test

I am able to get Spring Boot integration to generate a random free port to launch itself on. But I also need a free port for Redis.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyApplication.class}, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
@WebIntegrationTest(randomPort = true, value = "server.port:0")
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"local"})
public class SegmentSteps {

    private static final String HOST_TEMPLATE = "http://localhost:%s";

    // Needs to be a random open port
    private static final int REDIS_PORT = 6380;

    private String host;
    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    private int serverPort;

    private RedisServer redisServer;

    @Before
    public void beforeScenario() throws Exception {
        host = String.format(HOST_TEMPLATE, serverPort);
        redisServer = RedisServer.builder()
                .redisExecProvider(RedisExecProvider.defaultProvider())
                .port(REDIS_PORT)
                .setting("bind 127.0.0.1")
                .build();
        redisServer.start();
    }

    ...
}
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use Spring Framework's [`SocketUtils`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/SocketUtils.html) to get an available port:

```
int redisPort = SocketUtils.findAvailableTcpPort();
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the same number in the context?

Comment: Or do I just use an int bean? With a qualifier?

Comment: @ptimson, I don't understand your question. Could you elaborate?

Comment: `SocketUtils` is deprecated _as of Spring Framework 5.3.16, to be removed in 6.0_

Comment: Redis doesn't support starting with a "port: 0" configuration to select a random port. See https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/7652#issuecomment-672941031

Comment: It's now `org.springframework.test.util.TestSocketUtils.findAvailableTcpPort()`

Answer (score 1):

Here in 2021, this is the best way to do it I think. This requires spring-boot >= 2.3 / spring framework 5.2.5 and it uses [@DynamicPropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-dynamic-property-sources) annotation.

Helper class:

```java
@TestConfiguration
public class TestRedisConfiguration
{
    private RedisServer redisServer;

    public TestRedisConfiguration(
            @Value("${spring.redis.port}")
                    int redisPort
    )
    {
        this.redisServer = new RedisServer(redisPort);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct()
    {
        redisServer.start();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void preDestroy()
    {
        redisServer.stop();
    }

    static public void configurePort(DynamicPropertyRegistry r)
    {
        int port = SocketUtils.findAvailableTcpPort();
        r.add("spring.redis.host", () -> "localhost");
        r.add("spring.redis.port", () -> port);
    }
}
```

In your test class (or base class):

```java
@SpringBootTest
@Import({TestRedisConfiguration.class})
public abstract class BaseTestFullContext
{
...
   @DynamicPropertySource
    static public void properties(DynamicPropertyRegistry r)
    {
        TestRedisConfiguration.configurePort(r);
    }
...
```

Comment: [`SocketUtils`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.16/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/SocketUtils.html) is deprecated in 5.3.16 and slated for removal in 6.0: "these utilities make no guarantee about the subsequent availability of a given port and are therefore unreliable. Instead of using SocketUtils to find an available local port for a server, it is recommended that you rely on a server's ability to start on a random port that it selects or is assigned by the operating system."

Comment: `TestSocketUtils` is the "successor" of `SocketUtils` in newer Spring versions.
If you only need the `TestRedisConfiguration` in a single place (test or base class) I prefer having it as a static *nested* class; then you can omit the `@Import` and everything is in one place

Comment: sorry, you will still need the `@Import`, my bad

Answer (score -1):

You could also run your Redis within Docker by either using a Java client of your choosing or by leveraging [Overcast](http://blog.xebia.com/fast-and-easy-integration-testing-with-docker-and-overcast/). If using Overcast, by activating `exposeAllPorts` option, your Redis would be bound to a random port on the host machine.

As for how you can enable the property in the context - it would require some work but you could implement a listener that would start up Docker containers and put the ports as properties in an environment:

```
public class IntegrationTestBootstrapApplicationListener implements
    ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent>, Ordered {

    public static final int DEFAULT_ORDER = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 4;
    public static final int PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME = "integrationTestProps";

    private int order = DEFAULT_ORDER;

    public void setOrder(int order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return this.order;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent event) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = event.getEnvironment();

        if (!environment.getPropertySources().contains(PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME)) {
            CloudHost itestHost = CloudHostFactory.getCloudHost("redis");
            itestHost.setup();

            String host = itestHost.getHostName();
            // fetch the dynamic port from Docker
            int port = itestHost.getPort(6379); 

            // alternatively, skip the whole CloudHost setup above and just use:
            // int port = SocketUtils.findAvailableTcpPort();

            environment.getPropertySources().addLast(
              new MapPropertySource(
                PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME, Collections.<String, Object> singletonMap(
                  "redis.port", port));
            );
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Great will have to give this a go - probably abit overkill for this project

Comment: Yeah, figured, but it's a great option in case you need to provision several external resources (say, Redis, RabbitMQ, PostgreSQL, and an FTP server).