# sharing properties between spring and non-spring tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-test

Most of my DB tests don't use Spring because this way they start much faster. But I want to also run smoke tests that actually run entire Spring Boot application.

And I would like to have DB connection parameters in one place. To do it I think I have 2 options:

1. simulate / reuse Spring's properties loading in my non-Spring tests
2. inject my properties calculated in runtime (annotation with a constant is not an option) into Spring configuration in smoke tests

Any idea how to achieve any of those? Or maybe there is some simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

You can export your database connection parameters as system properties named exactly as properties from your `application.properties`. Thanks to the way Spring Boot handles externalized configuration, those values will override those from the properties (or YAML, whichever you use) file in Spring configuration, and you then just need to use the system properties in your non-Spring tests.

Although I would suggest making those DB tests a part of Spring suite, too - you actually gain speed only when you execute a single test; unless you have `@DirtiesContext` tests or tests that use different `@ActiveProfiles` annotation, Spring will cache the application context and only initialize it once per whole test suite.

Here's a quote from [the official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testing-ctx-management):

> The Spring TestContext Framework provides consistent loading of Spring ApplicationContexts and WebApplicationContexts as well as caching of those contexts. **Support for the caching of loaded contexts is important, because startup time can become an issue — not because of the overhead of Spring itself, but because the objects instantiated by the Spring container take time to instantiate.** For example, a project with 50 to 100 Hibernate mapping files might take 10 to 20 seconds to load the mapping files, and incurring that cost before running every test in every test fixture leads to slower overall test runs that reduce developer productivity.
>
> **By default, once loaded, the configured ApplicationContext is reused for each test. Thus the setup cost is incurred only once per test suite, and subsequent test execution is much faster.** In this context, the term test suite means all tests run in the same JVM — for example, all tests run from an Ant, Maven, or Gradle build for a given project or module.

Comment: system properties are ugly but i admit, they get the job done. i'll wait for some 'less invasive' solutions before accepting your answer. migrating tests to spring is not an option: ~200ms vs 5s each time. that's a big difference for TDD

Comment: Agreed but I don't see an easier way out. I myself have always preferred [the approach of adding an environment prepared application listener](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38985183/4657798) but that is a bit heavyweight for your use case. And in your case, you'd have to have a static Map field somewhere to hold the configuration that you'd pass on to the listener so I think system properties are still a less invasive way to go

Answer (score 0):

You can store your DB connection properties in a dedicated Java `db.properties` file that you can load for your standard tests and Spring Boot tests.

You can then instruct Spring Boot to load `db.properties` in addition to your standard Spring Boot application properties files by specifying a custom `spring.config.location`.

The [Application property files](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) section of the Spring Boot reference manual provides all the details you should need.